# Compressing the audio files

Tags: windows

I have a 1.5gb music folder in my laptop that I want to compress and then send it to my phone. So I wanna know does the size of the file remain same as it was before after unzipping and do zipped folders open in android phones

Answer (score 3):

[Android should be able to unpack zip archives, at least using additional apps](https://www.howtogeek.com/215539/HOW-TO-OPEN-AND-CREATE-ZIP-FILES-ON-AN-ANDROID-DEVICE/), but that is not related to Ubuntu.

How tightly a file can be compressed depends mainly on its file type. Formats like mp3 are already strongly compressed by themselves, putting them in a zip will not gain much, if anything. Uncompressed formats like wav though can shrink significantly when compressing them.

Other than this rough separation in internally compressed/uncompressed file formats, you can't get an approximate number of how small your files really become other than by simply trying it out.